# MySQL query to generate only negative daily differences

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I'm learning mysql and am having difficult time getting my head around more complicated outputs - mainly the logic part... I have a simple database that contains 2 tables with 1 connection - design is here https://prnt.sc/mfmwji

I need to create a report that displays daily balance of only negative states (so only if person is in a negative balance) for the past 6 months.

I've put together query that displays only differences when they're negative, but it does not 'connect' them to rows before them... only displays the withdraws so to say.
I've played around with query but this is the 'best' thing I've came up with... I've tried to wrap the difference with sum function but that just sums the whole thing and doesn't return daily difference.

```
SELECT
    T1.name AS Name,
    T2.withdraw - T2.deposit AS Difference,
    DATE_FORMAT(T2.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Date
FROM
    users AS T1
INNER JOIN transactions AS T2
ON
    T1.id = T2.user_id
WHERE
    (T2.withdraw - T2.deposit) > 0
```

The query returns this output (its just a part of result since I got 100 results) 
http://prntscr.com/mfn0xf

The deposits and withraws for Pearl Champlin so you get the idea are: 
http://prntscr.com/mfn15a

I've tried to check other questions on SO but they usually point to other problems and are not specific to my problem.

Thanks in advance for any information you think I should check out!

Comment: We need example data and expected results (no images) it is hard to read a query or giving solid comments/answers without.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRXgyePFoF8VPax3NxMQNp/0  I've listened to @RaymondNijland and added stuff so you guys can have a deeper look into the query and try stuff into more detail. MySQL is 5.6.34 version

Comment: Well can you make a smaller SQL fiddle for `Shanel Torp` only (for example) and the expected result based on that data you can use a [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) to generate formatted text.. This way we can verify our query and we have less data to look in and work with.

Comment: I've added only Shanel Torp with her transactions - didn't understand how to use the the tool you linked to get 2 tables into it so I've used fiddle again https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uK5bDWYPDVx5UdyFKyzPr/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the balance up to date. Then, in an outer query, you can filter for where that balance is negative:

```
select   *
from     (
          select      u.name,
                      t.date,
                      t.deposit - t.withdraw action,
                      ( select sum(deposit - withdraw)
                        from   transactions
                        where  user_id = u.id
                        and    date <= t.date ) as balance
          from        users as u
          inner join  transactions as t
                  on  u.id = t.user_id
         ) balances
where    balance < 0       
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Wau, you're next level sir! Thank you a ton really!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you asked. It shows the report for one user. I don't know if there is a way to make this for all the user at the same time. Maybe it can help you to find what you want.

```
SELECT
    PreAgg.name,
    (PreAgg.withdraw - PreAgg.deposit) AS Difference,
    @PrevBal := @PrevBal + (PreAgg.withdraw - PreAgg.deposit) AS Balance
FROM
    (SELECT
        T1.name,
        T2.deposit,
        T2.withdraw,
        (T2.withdraw - T2.deposit) AS Difference,
        T1.id
     FROM
        users AS T1
     INNER JOIN transactions AS T2
     ON
        T1.id = T2.user_id
     ORDER BY
        T2.id ) AS PreAgg,
       (SELECT @PrevBal := 0) as InitialVar
WHERE PreAgg.id = 1
```

Comment: I've added the database to db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRXgyePFoF8VPax3NxMQNp/0 where you can check out the query - I've tried to run yours and the result is not the one I'm looking for. Thanks for help tho! Appreciate it

Comment: What result are you expecting? I don't understand when you say "it does not 'connect' them to rows before them"

Comment: So I want to output to be rows of people that had a negative balance - so when the withdraw was larger than positive balance that day - and to show that amount at the day the withdraw happened (the cause of negative balance) - did I explain it better? It's hard since English is not my primary language

Comment: But isn't your request already doing the job? It shows all the transactions with a negative balance at the day?

Comment: Or you want to take in account all the deposits and withdraws that the person did before and have the account balance at the day?

Comment: Exactly @Dialex ! That's my goal - to take in the account of previous deposits and withdraws

Comment: I updated my answer. I found a way to show the balance per day for one user. But I honestly have no idea if you can do it for all the users at the same time (you should find a way to reinitialize ```@PrevBal``` to 0 when it's a new user). Maybe it can help

Comment: Thank you for your effort - I'll try to make something out of it! It's looking better than what I did by a large margin! Thank you kind sir!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Good luck :-)